# How do I get the functions from one streamlit py file(second page of same app) to the main app file without importing the file?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, streamlit

I need to create a streamlit website with two pages. To achieve this, I must create two separate Python files in streamlit, each containing the code for one page. Normally, when you need to access functions and variables from one Python file to another, you just import the file. However, in this case, importing the second file into the first (or vice versa) also copies the frontend. Unfortunately, I am unable to share the code, but if you require further clarification, please do not hesitate to ask.

I attempted to import the necessary model directly to the main file using torch.hub.load, but it failed because my work PC lacks internet access for security reasons. I received a recommended solution involving obj = __ import__(second.py), but that also proved ineffective. As a beginner in streamlit and python, I may have overlooked something basic. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know anything about Streamlit, but for web pages in general, the server will be _stateless._ That means, when it's showing your page 1, it knows nothing about your page 2, and vice versa. Your two python programs almost certainly will not be executed at the same time. If you need the two pages to share data, then you probably will need to store the shared data on some database server, distinct from the web server. Maybe Streamlit provides some way to help you with that, but I wouldn't know. Like I said, I know nothing about Streamlit.